# how to make an executable file java using xuggler libraries

Tags: java, executable-jar, xuggle, xuggler

I made an executable jar, exporting my project with eclipse.
Its working on my laptop but in another one, it doesn't work. I think because `xuggler` is not installed on that one.Is there any way to get my software working in others laptops? Maybe I should make the executable file in another way.
Thanks for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen on the xuggler homepage you'll have to install xuggler on every machine you intent to use your program.
Therefore you won't be able to make an independent *executable jar*.

One solution would be to ship the xuggler install with your program and ask the user if he would install it in order to run your program.

Answer (score 2):

As of 5.3 (which will be released next week) Xuggler can run on most common operating systems WITHOUT an installer.  You will need to include the contents of xuggle-xuggler.jar in your program, but that should be it.  Enjoy.

Comment: Glad I stumbled across this - great news! :-)

Comment: @Xuggle I am fairly new to java.How do I include contents of xuggle-xuggler.jar in my program? and I am not able to see any tutorials [here](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction). How do I start? Install xuggler in my system. But I am still confused, will the user of my application also need to install xuggler?